# React Native Expo SDK 44 expo-camera crashing when Eas Build is being used

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

Expo SDK 44: expo-camera is crashing when the application is run on Eas build while it works fine on the normal expo go application. The logs of the errors are attached below.

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlZzz.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and this [thread](https://forums.expo.dev/t/barcodescanner-crashes-standalone-but-not-on-dev/59305/4) helped me.

I was using `expo-camera` for reading barcodes, and adding `expo-barcode-scanner` to my `package.json` solved it for me.

Comment: It worked but needed to add ``expo-face-detector`` as well along with ``expo-barcode-scanner`` in the package.json.

Comment: Glad it worked! I would really appreciate it if you accept the answer (if you feel it helped you).